# Misunderstandment of map parameters in Haskell

Tags: haskell, typeerror

I'm trying to create a function, which will multiply each element in a list called s by a parameter x.

First, I experimented around in ghci and found that `fn1 s = map (* 2) s` works. The I tried to make the function more general by including the factor x as a parameter `fn2 x s = map (* x) s`. However this leads to an error, when I call the function:

```
<interactive>:12:1: error:
    • Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Num [a]
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall a. (Num a, Num [a]) => [[a]] -> [[a]]
```

After some additional experimentation I found that I can solve the problem by surrounding the * operator with ()

```
fn3 x s = map ((*) x) s
```

What I need help with is why the latter piece of code works while the previous does not.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you, by any chance, forget to provide the factor parameter when calling `fn2`? Can you show how you're calling it exactly?

Comment: It seems that in the roughly ten times I checked the code I failed to remember the correct order of parameters.
Thank you :)

Comment: @Bruno The error messages will be much easier to read if you give every top-level function definition an explicit type signature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would happen if you forget to provide the `x` parameter when calling `fn2`, for example:

```
> fn2 [1,2,3]
```

The compiler sees `[1,2,3]` where `x` should be, and it also sees `(* x)` in the body of the function, and it reckons that `[1,2,3]` must be a valid argument for operator `*`. And since operator `*` is defined in type class `Num`, the compiler infers that there must be an instance `Num [a]` - which is exactly what it says in the error message.

The result of such call would be another function, which still "expects" the missing parameter `s` and once given it, will return a list of the same type as `s`. Since it's clear from the provided arguments that `x :: [a]`, and you're using `map` to transform `x` to the same type, the compiler infers that `s :: [[a]]`, and so the result of calling `fn2` like that is `[[a]] -> [[a]]`, which is what the error message says.

Now, the requirement of an instance `Num [a]` in itself is not a big deal. In fact, if you enable the `FlexibleContexts` extension (as the error message tells you), this particular error goes away, and you will get another one, complaining that there is no instance `Num [a]` for any `a`. And *that* is the real problem. There is no instance `Num [a]`, because, well, lists are not numbers.